# How do you define summary and extension of weighted finite state transducers?

Tags: math, nlp, discrete-mathematics, finite-automata, state-machine

So reading through this paper:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/fla.pdf

I see that a weighted finite state transducer (WFST) is a semiring, and many operations on WFST can be expressed in terms of "sum" and "product" over the semiring. For example, composition of Transducers one and two is:

```
(T1 ◦ T2)(x, y) = ⊕ z∈∆∗ T1(x, z)⊗T2(z, y)
```

But I can't seem to find an explanation on how do pure sum and product of WFST, and am having trouble backing out the operation from the composition example above.

A demonstration over this example would be much appreciated:

```
format: state1 state2, input alphabet : output alphabet, transition prob

T1 

0 1 a : b, 0.1
0 2 b : b, 0.2
2 3 b : b, 0.3
0 0 a : a, 0.4
1 3 b : a, 0.5

T2

0 1 b : a, 0.1
1 2 b : a, 0.2
1 1 a : d, 0.3
1 2 a : c, 0.4
```

Example taken from: [How to perform FST (Finite State Transducer) composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649474/how-to-perform-fst-finite-state-transducer-composition)

--------------- update ------------

Found the answer in this document: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/hwa.pdf

page 12

Comment: Might do better on math overflow.   Great question.

Comment: Thanks! I just found the answer in this document, page 12

Comment: @chibro2 you should add answer in answer section below,...

Comment: @chibro2 : Nice! Please include the link and provide an answer to your question as a SO answer (instead of including the answer in the question itself)